# Get-MsolUserRole Azure AD V2 cmdlet equivalent

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I currently try to migrate an existing PowerShell script that uses the old MSOnline PowerShell module to the AzureAD (V2) module. I am able to replace most of the cmdlets but I don't find a replacement for the [`Get-MsolUserRole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msoluserrole?view=azureadps-1.0) cmdlet to retrieve administrator roles for a **specific user**.

The similar AzureAD (V2) cmdlets doesn't allow me to query the roles by the objectId of the **user** (they require the role objectid).
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest equivalent is `Get-AzureADUserMembership`, but since this will also include other membership (e.g. group memberships), you will need to filter the results down to only directory roles:

```bsh
Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId "user@example.com" -All $true `
| Where-Object { $_.ObjectType -eq "Role" }
```